# "개사"는 漢字로 쓰면 "改寫"이나 "改詞"입니까?

Tags: sino-korean-words

Translating the lyrics of one song into another language and then singing it is called "개사". It's clear that this is a 漢字語 (한자어), but which one of them is correct?

Answer (score 2):

It would be **改詞**, [from 고칠 개 and 말 사](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/26601e9a4110452b9f68649f34cb9153); it is this 말 사 that is used in the 한자어 *hanja-eo* **歌詞 가사**.

개사 is the hangeul equivalent of many 한자어, but **改寫**, relatively common in Modern Standard Mandarin Chinese, is not listed in the Modern Korean dictionaries that I have access to. Instead, the closest is **開寫** (in itself vanishingly rare in [Modern Chinese](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%96%8B%E5%AF%AB)), which is defined as:

> 글로 써서 나타냄.

... that is, basically to 'start writing'. But I imagine this is only used in historical texts, or in reference to history.